# How to update firestore collection based on other docs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an order form that limits how many items you can order based on the `stock` of the item. I have a `menu` collection which has items

```js
// menu 

{ id: "lasagna", name: "Lasagna", price: 10, stock: 15 }
{ id: "carrot-soup", name: "Carrot Soup", price: 10, stock: 15 }
{ id: "chicken-pot-pie", name: "Chicken Pot Pie", price: 10, stock: 15 }
```

And an `orders` collection

```js
// orders

{ id: <auto>, name: "Sarah", cart: {lasagna: 1, carrot-soup: 3}, ... }
{ id: <auto>, name: "Wendy", cart: {chicken-pot-pie: 2, carrot-soup: 1}, ... }
{ id: <auto>, name: "Linda", cart: {lasagna: 3}, ... }
```

4 `carrot-soup` has been ordered so the `stock` should be updated

```js
// updated stock

{ id: "carrot-soup", name: "Carrot Soup", stock: 11 }
```

Orders are inserted from my `Form` component

```js
function Form(props) {   
  // ... 

  // send order to firestore
  const onSubmit = async _event => {
    try {
      const order = { cart, name, email, phone, sms }
      dispatch({ action: "order-add" })
      const id = await addDocument(store, "orders", order)
      dispatch({ action: "order-add-success", payload: { ...order, id } })
    }
    catch (err) {
      dispatch({ action: "order-add-error", payload: err })
    }
  }
  return <form>...</form>
}
```

This is my database `addDocument` function

```js
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimeStamp } from "firebase/firestore"

async function addDocument(store, coll, data) {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(store, coll), { ...data, timestamp: serverTimestamp() })
  return docRef.id
}
```

How should I decrement the `stock` field in my `menu` collection?
Ideally the client should have only **read** access to `menu` but to update the `stock` the client would need write access.

Another possibility is to have the client query the `orders`, sum the items, and subtract them from the read-only `menu`. But giving the client read access to other people's orders seems wrong too.

I am new to firestore and don't see a good way to design this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deffinitely use a cloud function to update the stock. Create a function `onCreate` and `onDelete` functions trigger. If users can change data you would also need to `onWrite` function trigger.

Depending on the amount of data you have you woould need to create a custom `queue` system to update the stock. Belive me! It took me almost 2 years to figure out to solve this. I have even spoken with the Firebase engeeners at the last Firebase Summit in Madrid.

Usualy you would use a `transaction` to update the state. I would recommend you to do so if you don't have to much data to store.

In my case the amount of data was so large that those transactions would randomly fail so the stock wasn't correct at all. You can see my StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085147/5519300). The first time I tought I had an answer. You know it took me years to solve this because I asked the same question on a Firebase Summit in Amsterdam. I asked one of the Engeeners who worked on the Realtime Database before they went to Google.

There is a solution to store the stock in `chunks` but even that would cause random errors with our data. Each time we improved our solution the random errors reduced but still remained.

The solution we are still using is to have a custom `queue` and work each change one by one. The downside of this is that it takes some time to calculate a lot of data changes but it is 100% acurate.

Just in case we still have a "recalculator" who recalculates one day again and checks if everything worked as it should.

Sorry for the long aswer. For me it looks like you are building a similar system like we have. If you plan to create a warehouse management system like we did I would rather point you to the right direction.

In the end it depends on the amount of data you have and how often or fast you change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Tarik Huber's advice.

First I include `functions` and `admin`

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
admin.initializeApp()
```

Then I create `increment` and `decrement` helpers

```js
const menuRef = admin.firestore().collection("menu")

const increment = ([ id, n ]) =>
  menuRef.doc(id).update({
    stock: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(n)
  })

const decrement = ([ id, n ]) =>
  increment([ id, n * -1 ])
```

Here is the `onCreate` and `onDelete` hooks

```js
exports.updateStockOnCreate =
  functions
    .firestore
    .document("orders/{orderid}")
    .onCreate(snap => Promise.all(Object.entries(snap.get("cart") ?? {}).map(decrement)))

exports.updateStockOnDelete =
  functions
    .firestore
    .document("orders/{orderid}")
    .onDelete(snap => Promise.all(Object.entries(snap.get("cart") ?? {}).map(increment)))
```

To handle `onUpdate` I compare the cart `before` and `after` using a `diff` helper

```js
exports.updateStockOnUpdate =
  functions
    .firestore
    .document("orders/{orderid}")
    .onUpdate(snap => Promise.all(diff(snap.before.get("cart"), snap.after.get("cart")).map(increment)))
```

Here is the `diff` helper

```js
function diff (before = {}, after = {}) {
  const changes = []
  const keys = new Set(Object.keys(before).concat(Object.keys(after)))
  for (const k of keys) {
    const delta = (before[k] ?? 0) - (after[k] ?? 0)
    if (delta !== 0)
      changes.push([k, delta])
  }
  return changes
}
```